# How to get Employee Number using REST API

Tags: rest-api, profile, user

I have successfully authenticated from my application using OAuth2 and I'm able to get UserName, UserId and few other things, but I can't get EmployeeNumber which is stored in User profile. How that can be done using REST API, for my authenticated user?

Comment: What have you currently tried to get that field ? Knowing so may help others in answering. (You can update your question with additional infor, that way it's not hidden in the comments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the API point of view, `EmployeeNumber` is just the same as `Username`, `Id` and any other field. It may be field level security that is preventing you from seeing it - check the settings on the `User` object against the profile of the user you're using to access the API.

Comment: There were several issues with my approach. At the end, I used this: https://apigee.com/console/salesforce to troubleshoot and to make requests that will work.